# retentionInDays error with ansible and aws cloudwatch log group

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to execute the `ansible` example for the `aws cloudwatch log group` as described here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/ecs_ecr_module.html

```
- cloudwatchlogs_log_group:
    state: present
    log_group_name: test-log-group
    tags: { "Name": "test-log-group", "Env" : "QA" }
```

#### And getting the following error:

> File
>   \"/var/folders/k5/7wr8brn12mncybzndxyl31zr0000gq/T/ansible_cloudwatchlogs_log_group_payload_2pmq9jyc/ansible_cloudwatchlogs_log_group_payload.zip/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/cloudwatchlogs_log_group.py\",
>   line 262, in main\nKeyError: 'retentionInDays'\n",

#### I am using:

ansible 2.9.6
python version = 3.8.2

Comment: seems to be a bug..https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/47945

Comment: @error404 is there already a solution?

Comment: had a quick looks...seems like a fix is there not sure on the status of the fix..please check   :)